# how to repair a broken install of WMF 5.1 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have tried to install WMF 5.1 on a Windows 7 laptop as I needed the latest powershell (for vagrant). The install failed in the middle and now, WMF 5.1 is reported as installed, but powershell is not updated. If I try to uninstall WMF 5.1 it fails. If I try to re-install it, it fails too, as it's reported as already installed...
Is there a magic recipe to re-install WMF 5.1 and have the latest powershell installed?

Thanks,

François

Comment: try to uninstall the update KB3191566 from control panel.

Comment: I assume you meet all the [prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure)?  You indicated you wanted to use the latest version of PowerShell, but don't specify which version, you believe that to be.  Difficult to search.  The reason I ask, there is a version of PowerShell, which can be installed in addition, to the current version of PowerShell.  Trying to determine what version you are actually trying to install.

Comment: Hi,I need a version at least 5.0.

Comment: I tried to install the standalone version of powershell (6.x?) but it fails as it requires WMF 5.0 or 5.1 to install...

Comment: And KB3191566 is not installed...

Comment: Unless you are planning to do crossplatform powershell do not use v6

Comment: What errors do you get?